# Close menu on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

looking for a little bit of help, im working with this codepen menu:
http://codepen.io/ettrics/pen/JoaaxW

but I'd like to make sure that the menu closes when a user clicks on a menu item. (and perhaps clicks somewhere on the menu background too)

I'm wanting to have a one page site so that if the user clicks on the item it scrolls them to that section,  at the moment the menu does not close when using the section ID in as the href which creates the problem.

Any help much appreciated!

CODE:

```js
(function() {

  var Menu = (function() {
    var burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
    var menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
    var menuList = document.querySelector('.menu__list');
    var brand = document.querySelector('.menu__brand');
    var menuItems = document.querySelectorAll('.menu__item');

    var active = false;

    var toggleMenu = function() {
      if (!active) {
        menu.classList.add('menu--active');
        menuList.classList.add('menu__list--active');
        brand.classList.add('menu__brand--active');
        burger.classList.add('burger--close');
        for (var i = 0, ii = menuItems.length; i < ii; i++) {
          menuItems[i].classList.add('menu__item--active');
        }

        active = true;
      } else {
        menu.classList.remove('menu--active');
        menuList.classList.remove('menu__list--active');
        brand.classList.remove('menu__brand--active');
        burger.classList.remove('burger--close');
        for (var i = 0, ii = menuItems.length; i < ii; i++) {
          menuItems[i].classList.remove('menu__item--active');
        }

        active = false;
      }
    };

    var bindActions = function() {
      burger.addEventListener('click', toggleMenu, false);
    };

    var init = function() {
      bindActions();
    };

    return {
      init: init
    };

  }());

  Menu.init();

}());
```

```css
$primary-color: #38C5B9;

@mixin easeOut {
  transition: all .4s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1)
}

@mixin tablet {
  @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    @content;
  }
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: $primary-color;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  color: white;
  line-height: 1.5;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.header {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 5;
  width: 100%;
}

.burger {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  right: 25px;
  top: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: rotateY(0);
  @include easeOut;
  
  &__patty {
    width: 28px;
    height: 2px;
    margin: 0 0 4px 0;
    background: white;
    @include easeOut;
    
    &:last-child {
      margin-bottom: 0;
    }
  }
  
  // transform burger into 'x'
  &--close {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    
    .burger__patty {
      &:nth-child(1) {
        transform: rotate(45deg) translate(4px, 4px);
      }
      &:nth-child(2) {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      &:nth-child(3) {
        transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(5px, -4px);
      }
    }
  }
}

.menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
  
  &--active {
    visibility: visible;
  }
  
  &__brand,
  &__list {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  &__list {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: mix(black, $primary-color, 20);
    list-style-type: none;
    transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
    @include easeOut;
    
    &--active {
      transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
  }
  
  &__brand {
    background: $primary-color;
    @include easeOut;
    transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    
    &--active {
      transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
  }
  
  &__item {
    transform: translate3d(500px, 0, 0);
    @include easeOut;
    
    &--active {
      transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
  }
  
  &__link {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 30px;
    padding: 15px 0;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    @include easeOut;
    
    &:before {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 50%;
      width: 10px;
      height: 2px;
      background: white;
      transform: translateX(-50%);
      @include easeOut;
    }
    
    &:hover {
      &:before {
        width: 100%;
      }
    }
  }
  
  // add delay to each menu item
  @for $x from 1 through 6 {
    .menu__item:nth-child(#{$x}) {
      transition-delay: $x * .1s;
    }
  }
}

// responsive tablet view
@include tablet {
 ul.menu__list,
 div.menu__brand {
  float: none;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 0;

   &--active {
     transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
   }
 }

 .menu__list {
   height: 75vh;
   transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
 }

 .menu__link {
   font-size: 24px;
 }

 .menu__brand {
   height: 25vh;
   transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);

   .logo {
     width: 90px;
     height: 90px;
   }
 }
}

// make the demo look nice, not required for your own use.
.logo {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: lighten(black, 10);
  border-radius: 50%;
}

h1, h2, h3, p {
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: 400;
}

main {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 8vw;
  
  h1 > a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 48px;
    font-weight: 300;
  }
}

.support {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 24px;
  color: rgba(black, 0.6);
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="burger">
    <div class="burger__patty"></div>
    <div class="burger__patty"></div>
    <div class="burger__patty"></div>
  </div>

  <nav class="menu">
    <div class="menu__brand">
      <a href=""><div class="logo"></div></a>
    </div>
    <ul class="menu__list">
      <li class="menu__item"><a href="" class="menu__link">Work</a></li>
      <li class="menu__item"><a href="" class="menu__link">About</a></li>
      <li class="menu__item">
        <a href="https://twitter.com/ettrics" target="_blank" class="menu__link menu__link--social"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu__item">
        <a href="https://dribbble.com/ettrics" target="_blank" class="menu__link menu__link--social">
          <i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>

<main>
  <h1><a href="http://ettrics.com" target="_blank">Ettrics</a></h1>
  <h2>A Full-Screen Menu, showcasing your brand and website navigation.</h2>
  <p class="support">With support for IE10 & latest versions of Chrome, Safari, and Firefox.</p>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add something like

```
$("body").one ("click", "*", function () {
  HideMenu (); // function to hide your menu or simulate a click on the 'X' sign
});
```

When you open the menu.